# Reading file, outputting UTF-8/Unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to read a file and compare the characters. However, when I print out after reading each line with:

```
    with open('Q1.txt') as f:
        content = f.read().splitlines()
```

I'm getting '\x80', '\xe2', '\x9d', etc.

What do these mean and how can I get rid of them?

Thanks.

Comment: If you use Python 3 instead, you can pass an encoding! `open('Q1.txt', encoding='utf-8')`.

Answer (score 2):

The `open()` builtin does not handle any text encoding in Python 2.x. Multi-byte characters come through as raw hex. You can use the `io` module to get a more capable `open` function that provides a parameter to define the encoding:

```
import io
with io.open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  ...
```

Conveniently, this works in both python 2.6+ and 3.x so you won't have mysterious encoding problems if the code is ported to py3k later. BTW, the `open` builtin in 3.x is actually an alias for `io.open`. The backported version in 2.6+ has the exact same functionality. The `io` module is intended to supersede the `codecs` module and has some internal improvements so it is preferable to use its `open` in new code.

Comment: Thanks. But now I'm getting lots of u's all over the place. How would I get rid of those?? Thanks again.

Comment: You don't. Unicode strings are a separate type from the plain 8-bit str type in 2.x. The "u" prefix is used to distinguish their printed representation in code and interactive sessions. They are not present in the actual string. Python 3 made unicode the universal string type and doesn't require the "u" prefix if it bothers you.

Comment: So if I need to compare characters, there's no way?

Comment: The `unicode` type in 2.x works just like `str`. You can still do whatever string operations you need. Some 2.x code may fail if it isn't written to accept `unicode` objects but the standard library will handle them fine.

Answer (score 1):

From the Unicode How-to docs: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('Q1.txt', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    print(repr(line))
```

In Python 3, just use the builtin `open` with the context manager:

```
with open('Q1.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(f)
```